# Save data from application database to user's storage drive

Tags: c#, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I am making an application in visual studio 2012 for windows 8 C#. Now, please can anyone help me how to save data from application database to user's Storage drive.For example if we want to store "Assets/logo.png" from application database to user storage then how can we store it?
Thanking you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

For doing some thing like that you can try the below code..

```
     var file = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///assets/filename.png"));
     await file.CopyAsync(Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary, file.Name, Windows.Storage.NameCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
```

Let me know if this works. :)

Comment: Thank you for your help...but its giving an error 'await' operator can only be used with an async method.

Comment: I am having an button click event...I even tried making a private async void section...but it terminates application on button click event